# GWT + PHP encryption

Tags: php, security, gwt, encryption

Hello I am building a Website with a GWT frontend and the database connection through PHP.
I was wondering how I should encrypt en dycrypt data that's going to be send over the internet. Thanks,

Jan Behang.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure). Although if you are sending sensitive data to the client (which you shouldn't) you may want to use encryption (like RSA) on that data.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The main sensitive data that would be send is the login data from the users. I just want to secure that part.

Comment: The biggest problem is that my server does not provide https :S so i have to encrypt it

Answer (score 0):

You can connect through a [ssl connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html) to mysql server. Or if possible setup a [vpn tunnel](http://openvpn.net/) between client (gwt frontend) and mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same question you should ask yourself: If I have I website should I let users to login over SSL (https) or not?